# how to convert android.net.Uri with "content://" scheme to java.net.URI

Tags: java, android, uri

how to convert android.net.Uri with a "content://" scheme to java.net.URI 
=>content://media/external/video/media/100767

I am trying to convert `android.net.Uri` to `java.net.URI` like this:

`URI javaUri = new URI(myAndroidUri.toString());`

but I am getting this error:

```
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/100767 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.win.news/com.example.win.news.UploadNewsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute: content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F100767
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4067)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4110)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute: content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F100767
                  at java.io.File.checkURI(File.java:220)
                  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:177)
                  at com.example.win.news.UploadNewsActivity.videoToBase64(UploadNewsActivity.java:167)
                  at com.example.win.news.UploadNewsActivity.onActivityResult(UploadNewsActivity.java:129)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6549)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4063)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4110) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

please help..

Comment: What are you intending to do with the `java.net.URI`? `java.net` classes have nothing to do with the `ContentProvider` from Android.

Comment: Actually i am passing a video to my application server for that i need to convert that video into base64 string and for that i need to use the File class to convert the video into byte[] first like => File file =  new File(java.net.URI); then=> byte[] byteArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

Comment: You do not need `java.net.URI` to convert data into Base64 encoding. But you have other problems: you will run out of memory trying to convert a video into a Base64-encoded string, unless that video is *very* small (a few seconds or so, or very low resolution).

Comment: then how to fix  that?

Comment: maybe you need `android.util.Base64OutputStream` then? what actually is your goal?

Comment: as i said i want to send the video to the server

Comment: Talk to the people who created your Web app and ask how to upload a video to their server without converting it to Base64 in memory first.

Comment: ok but why do you want to grow your data by additional 33% (overhead made by base64)? if you really need it then, as i said use `Base64OutputStream`

Comment: @ CommonsWare i am the only person who is creating my app as well as server

Comment: so send it as it is - without any base64 encoding/decoding

Comment: @pskink how, can u give an example,because as far as i have learned ,i know to send any media file to the server we need to convert it to base64

Comment: there is no difference in sending raw bytes or base64 encoded bytes

Comment: there is,there datatype are different and  i dont know how to send a raw byte

Comment: and how do you want to send base64 encoded data?

Comment: by using sockets

Comment: so use sockets to send raw bytes, you dont need any base64 for that

Comment: we cannot pass raw bytes using sockets

Comment: why? what is the reason for that?

Comment: I am sorry, we can send raw bytes using sockets

Comment: but do u have answer of my original question,BTW thanks

Comment: no i dont have any kind of restriction

Comment: so use `DataOutputStream` for example for writing your data and `DataInputStream` for reading on the server side